# How to enable WPA/WPA2 in NetworkManager?

Tags: networkmanager, mate-desktop, wpa

I just reinstalled ArchLinux on my Thinkpad. I am a bit puzzled that the `network-manager-applet` only supports WEP encryption for wifi networks.

[image: network-manager-applet]

I already installed `wpa_supplicant` and `wireless_tools` as [suggested elsewhere on the internet](https://evilshit.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/how-to-make-networkmanager-and-network-manager-applet-work-on-arch-linux-with-gnome3/).

```
0 ✓ user@alcor ~ $ pacaur -Qs network
local/libnm-glib 1.4.4-1
    NetworkManager library
local/network-manager-applet 1.4.2-1
    Applet for managing network connections
local/networkmanager 1.4.4-1
    Network connection manager and user applications
local/nm-connection-editor 1.4.2-1
    NetworkManager GUI connection editor and widgets
```

I'm running ArchLinux with kernel 4.8.13-1-ARCH and the classic Mate Desktop environment in GTK-2 version.

How to enable WPA and WPA2 for the Network Manager Applet?

Comment: after installing `wpa_supplicant` you have restart the service and the applet?

Comment: Yes. Did a full system reboot meanwhile.

Comment: I can only give you a link, because I have no arch <https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant

Comment: I can't find anything specific about network-manager-applet on that wiki page. wpa-supplicant is installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was confusing two things: (1) creating new networks with the network-manager-applet only supports unencrypted or WEP encryption, as shown in the screenshot above. (2) Connecting to WPA secured wi-fi networks works with wireless_tools and wpa_supplicant installed.

However, it did not work in my case because I was using the network-manager-applet which was designed for GNOME on a MATE desktop environment. Here is the important [snippet from the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#No_prompt_for_password_of_secured_Wi-Fi_networks):

> ### Troubleshooting
>
> #### No prompt for password of secured Wi-Fi networks
>
> When trying to connect to a secured Wi-Fi network, no prompt for a password is shown and no connection is established. This happens when no keyring package is installed. An easy solution is to install [gnome-keyring](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=gnome-keyring). If you want the passwords to be stored in encrypted form, follow [GNOME Keyring](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring) to set up the *gnome-keyring-daemon*.

My mate installation was lacking a keyring. Installing `gnome-keyring` fixed the issue.

```
$ sudo pacman -S gnome-keyring
```

I am now able to use the WPA secured wi-fi networks again.

Answer (score 0):

`nm-applet` creates an Ad-hoc connection through that menu.

You might want to create a `hotspot` connection, and you can do that through "Edit Connections..."
[image: nm-applet Editing wifi-test]

You will then be able to select `WPA & WPA2 Personal` on `Wi-Fi Security` tab.